# GWT 2.7 exception when launching in dev mode from ec

Tags: exception, gwt, dev-mode

I am trying to run my GWT 2.7 application in dev mode from Eclipse (Kepler).  When I launch it I get the following exception. Can someone tell me what I can do to fix this?

Starting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@6c86fa3c: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler$1
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler$1
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.LazyList.addToArray(LazyList.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.addEventListener(ContextHandler.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStart(SecurityHandler.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStart(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doStart(SessionHandler.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:740)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:632)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1054)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:413)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it with the `-nosuperDevMode` flag?

GWT stopped supporting regular Dev Mode. The Browser's themselves (Chrome for sure) no longer support the API that enabled Dev Mode.  You probably want to look at [Super Dev Mode](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html), which is the currently supported method. You can debug in the browser with it

Comment: Thanks! I think that is the problem.

Comment: I am still having some trouble.  I am simply choosing Debug As -> Web Application (GWT Super Dev Mode). The console tab displays three similar exceptions. I read that this might be because I need a xerces jar. I tried adding xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar and it made no difference. Please excuse my relative inexperience as this is the first time I'm working with this stuff. The exceptions are: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature: http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd