# Unable to start GWT Development Mode, Exception in Jetty

Tags: eclipse, gwt

Eclipse version: 4.7.1a

GWT version: 2.7.0

The exception happens in both Super Dev or Legacy Dev mode.

[WARN] FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@3680cde9: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler$1
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler$1
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.LazyList.addToArray(LazyList.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.addEventListener(ContextHandler.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStart(SecurityHandler.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStart(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doStart(SessionHandler.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:740)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:632)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1054)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:413)

Comment: Try removing the security constraints from your web.xml

Comment: Thanks! However, I don't have any security-constraint in my web.xml.

Comment: try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873226/gwt-2-7-exception-when-launching-in-dev-mode-from-ec